# stratum value of NTP server in ntpq output

Tags: ntp

I have a stupid question, but I don't understand and i'd like to :)

I've set up a server *mysrv* and different client machines. The server is used as NTP server, and is configured with a Undisciplined Local Clock : with fudge 127.127.1.0 stratum 5

First question, if I well understand, my NTP server is now set as stratum 5 ?

Now on my clients, when I type a ntpq -p to check, they are synchronized so it's cool, but they see *mysrv* as stratum 6 (the column st of ntpq -p indicates 6) ... I was expecting 5...
Why ?

Thanx a lot

Comment: I think I get it, indeed with that configuration i'm not defining my server as stratum 5, i'm defining a source (well local source here) as stratum 5. So of course, if my server synchronizes on that source, my server is stratum 6 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your reasoning in the comment is correct. A server's stratum is X+1 where X is the stratum of the time source that the machine is synced to. Reference clocks, ie GPSDO, Rubidium, etc, are stratum 0. The time servers connected to these sources are stratum 1.